# send link on json data using ajax jquery

Tags: php, json, jquery

i m using auto suggest using [Ajax Json](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/) .

now when a user select a user name , i want to send user on the link of that user name

my json data is coming in this way

```
{
 query:'hel',
 suggestions:["hello world","hell boy ","bac to hell"],
 data:["2","26","34"]                       
}
```

now what i want that user goes to `http://userProfile.php?uid=26` on select username(suppose user select "hell boy")
how to do this??

**UPDATE:**
    i describe what i m doing step by step
    i m using a searchbox using jquery ajax, when user write some text on input box , we show (suggest) value regarading their search

*STEP 1.* when user write atleast(2 letter) `<input type="text" name="q" id="query" />`then a function(below) in invoked in which i send the value written on text box(eg. hell).

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var options, a;
    jQuery(function(){
       options = { serviceUrl:'rpc.php' };
       var a = $('#query').autocomplete({ 
        serviceUrl:'rpc.php',
        minChars:3, 
        delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
        maxHeight:400,
        width:300,
        zIndex: 9999,
        deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
      });
    });
 </script>
```

*STEP 2:* on `rpc.php`, i collect the data and show using JSON
 my final data come in below format

```
{
 query:'hell',
 suggestions:["hello world","hell boy ","bac to hell"],
 data:["2","26","34"]
```

}

where suggestion list having username and data is userid( from user_tables). above data comes in a div (on frontend) where user name displayed in a list

*STEP 3:* now if i select any username using uparrow, downarrow then that name is filled in input box,
 *STEP 4:* now what i want that when user select usename then page automatically goes to that user's profile section ( `userprofile.php?uid=2`)

Comment: I think you mean `JSON` and not jason. As for your question, you need to make it more clear exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @Abs it's json, thank u for pointing, now i have updated my question, please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look at the **[page you linked](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/)**, under the "how to use" section, you will see you can add an `onSelect` callback function:

```
 // callback function:
onSelect: function(value, data){ alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data); },
```

Now you should be able to access you data, and move your user to your required page.

e.g. something like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var options, a;
  jQuery(function() {
    options = {
      serviceUrl: 'rpc.php'
    };
    var a = $('#query').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: 'rpc.php',
        minChars: 3,
        delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
        maxHeight: 400,
        width: 300,
        zIndex: 9999,
        deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
        // callback function:
        onSelect: transferUser
      },
    });
  });

  function transferUser(value, data) {
    window.location.href = 'userprofile.php?uid=' + data;
  }    
</script>
```

*(note that I've not tested this, but it should give you some idea as to how to proceed!)*

It may also be worth noting that the latest version of jQuery UI [also has autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)